# Download and save the file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm downloading the file from my server using `urllib2.urlopen` method. I want to know how do you open the file and save it to a hard disk location in '/userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide'?

Here is the code:

```
def All_Channels(self):
     global __killthread__
     self.getControl(343).setLabel("0%")
     try:
         # DOWNLOAD THE XML SOURCE HERE
         url = ADDON.getSetting('allchannel.url')
         data = ''
         response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com/mydb.db")
         db_file = response.read()
         directory_path = os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', 'mydb.db')

     except:
        pass
```

I just want to download the file `mydb.db` to store it in my hard disk so I could then open the database.

I have no idea how to store the file in a hard disk after I have downloading them, I have been searching for some information but I couldn't find the answer.

If you can show me an example how I can save the file in a hard drive location after when I have download the file I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

For python 2.7 it is `urllib.urlretrieve(url,filename)` where `filename` is the place you want to store it.

Comment: thanks, but can you show me an example how i can store the file in a hard disk when using `urllib.urlretrieve`?

Comment: `urllib.urlretrieve(<url>,<path_on_your_hard_disk>/<filename>)`
Works on my machine